# Boolean Logic - Reduction - $a \vee (a \wedge b) = a$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How would I simplify / reduce the following equation using boolean identities/proofs?
$$a \vee (a \wedge b) = a$$
So far I've used the distributivity identity and got
$$(a\vee a) \wedge (a\vee b)$$
I then used the idempotence law to get
$$a \wedge (a\vee b)$$
Now I can't think of what to do next.

Comment: Use a truth table.

Comment: ~@JoelReyesNoche I'll try that out now, thank you.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably looking for this and not for truth-tables or what I'd written previously:

$$a \lor (a \land b)$$
$$(a \land \top) \lor (a \land b)$$
$$a \land (\top \lor b)$$
$$a \land \top$$
$$a$$

Comment: I think the original equation is also a redundance law :)

Comment: This is the correct answer, we haven't been taught about the Redundance Law unfortunately, thank you for the answer however.

Comment: @CSStudent Let me know if that's not what you want or if one of the steps you can't use.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan I never thought of simply adding a True value into the equation and going from there, thats pretty clever. Could you explain how line 2 turns into line 3? Slightly confused.

Comment: @CSStudent Recall that: $\top$ is the $\land$-identity (just like $1$ is the multiplicative identity). As regards the (2)-(3) move, do you remember how this works from high school algebra: $(a \cdot 1)+(a \cdot b) = a \cdot (1 + b)$? You're simply factoring the common $a$ out. It's the same principle. It's the reverse of distributivity.

Comment: Another important aspect of this answer is that it holds in *all* Boolean algebras (in fact, the identities used in the four steps hold in all distributive lattices with maximum element $\top$).

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & a\mathrm{~AND~}b & a\mathrm{~OR~}(a\mathrm{~AND~}b)\\\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I ended up with the same truth table as you, but how can I use this to prove the original equation is equal to just 'a' ? I'm starting to think I've missed something really obvious.

Comment: Their two columns are exactly the same.  Therefore the two expressions are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Joel, that explains it.